# How many tricks can the opponents claim if I revoke twice in one game?

Tags: bridge

I would like to know about revokes in bridge. Can the opponents claim 3 tricks?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

1. You mean "twice on one hand" and not "twice in one game" in your question title, as the two are very different (game is a scoring unit that can encompass many hands),
2. The second revoke was a failure to follow suit in the same suit as the first revoke, and
3. You are playing *Rubber Bridge* and not *Duplicate Bridge*;

then the following applies from [The Laws of Rubber Bridge](http://cdn.acbl.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Laws-of-Rubber-Bridge.pdf)

> **[Law 64] D.** there is no trick penalty for the established revoke
>
> ...
>
> 2. if the revoke was a subsequent revoke in the same
>    suit by the same player, ....

However, note the final paragraph of **Law 64**:

> When any established revoke, including one not subject to penalty, causes damage to the non-offending side insufficiently compensated by the Law, the
> offending side should transfer additional tricks so as to restore equity.

The easiest example of the exceptional case would be if the revoke allowed defender to a NT contract access to a running suit not otherwise with an entry, causing a makeable contract to be set more than one trick. Clearly a one trick penalty fails *to restore equity*, so a greater penalty should be applied.